# EventTime windowing from Kafka stream causing "Timestamp monotony violated" error

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading from a Kafka topic `data` that is partitioned based on a `equipmentId` field. There are a total of 15 partitions, one for each equipmentId.

The data in the topic looks like this: 

`{
  "timeStamp": "2018-05-03T14:32:04.910Z",
  "series": "production-output",
  "equipmentId": "5454-07",
  "value": 1
}`

In the same partition under the `equipmentId` there could be one of two records, either `production-output` or `production-input`.
My goal is to sum the production output for every minute based on eventTime.

This is what my code looks like so far

```
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.setParallelism(15);

        // Add kafka consumer to DataStream
    DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);

    DataStream keyedStream = stream
            .map(new SeriesMap())
            // Filter "production-output" seriesType
            .filter(new FilterFunction<Tuple4<Long, String, String, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter(Tuple4<Long, String, String, Double> data) throws Exception {
                    if (data.f1.equals("production-output")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            // Key on "equipmentId"
            .keyBy(2);

    DataStreamSink sink = keyedStream
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple4<Long, String, String, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple4<Long, String, String, Double> data) {
                    return data.f0;
                }
            })
            // Key on "equipmentId"
            .keyBy(2)
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(1))
            .sum(3)
            .print();
```

So I believe the issue comes from the `keyedStream` not creating a separate stream for every key.

if I were to execute this:

```
        DataStreamSink sink = keyedStream.print();
```

the output looks like :

```
15> (1525358087756,production-output,5454-07,1.0)
2> (1525358080269,production-output,5454-05,1.0)
2> (1525358085361,production-output,5454-05,1.0)
2> (1525358088469,production-output,5454-05,1.0)
2> (1525358097630,production-output,5454-05,1.0)
13> (1525358222081,production-output,5454-06,1.0)
13> (1525358223162,production-output,5454-06,1.0)
...
13> (1525358230305,production-output,5454-06,1.0)
13> (1525358234453,production-output,5454-06,1.0)
15> (1525358231998,production-output,5454-01,1.0)
15> (1525358231783,production-output,5454-10,1.0)
15> (1525358232803,production-output,5454-01,1.0)
15> (1525358233811,production-output,5454-01,1.0)
...
15> (1525358238878,production-output,5454-10,1.0)
```

So stream 15 is taking data for equipment 5454-10, 01 and 07
while streams 4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12 and 14 are not present in the output.

Not every machine will have data so I thought I could be facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090808/event-time-window-on-kafka-source-streaming)

However, what I think is happening is that more than 1 key is assigned to a thread [found in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710398/apache-flink-skewed-data-distribution-on-keyedstream)

any help is greatly appreciated!

**note:** I can guarantee that the order of timestamps is sequential per partition.

**UPDATE:** I did as Joshua DeWald suggested, and called `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on the **source**. I am no longer seeing the original issue with `Timestamp monotony violated` but am now running into [FLINK-5479](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5479).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that unless you can guarantee forward progress in timestamps *across* all partitions, because you are extracting timestamps and watermarks outside of your source, you will get this error.

What you can potentially do is use your `SeriesMap` class as a Kafka DeserializationSchema and then do the `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` against your Kafka source. Kafka will then have no issues with your timestamps moving forward separately within each partition, and the global watermark it emits will be the minimum of the watermark encountered across all partitions.

In other words, doing this your global event time will move forward at the rate of your slowest partition. The important caveat here is that each of your partitions must be emitting at least some data or else your forward progress of time will stop.

Note that time in Flink is global and not per key.